# Sorting based on the formula Calculation Solr

Tags: sorting, solr, solr4

I need to sort the solr results based on the following formula and in `desc`:

```
round (1000 * (1 - exp (-((( 1 * No. of Likes + 5 × No. of Comments + 10 × No. of Shares) ×  10000 ) / (fans_count ^ 0.8)) / 1000))
```

I used the below express in `sort` param:

```
rint(product(1000,sub(1,exp(-div(div(product(sum(product(1,likes_count),product(5,comments_count),product(10,shares_count)),10000),pow(fans_count,0.8)), 1000)))))
```

But it is throwing error:

```
Can't determine a Sort Order (asc or desc) in sort spec .............., pos=152"
```

I couldn't fix this error. Help pls

Comment: Are you sure the number of parentheses is balanced? Either try to remove spaces, or add `asc` or `desc` after your query. Does the formula work if you're not sorting by it, just returning the value in `fl`? Or try using the `_val_` [syntax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries#FunctionQueries-UsingFunctionQuery).

Comment: Yes. It is balanced.

Comment: What about the other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I changed the expression to:

```
rint(product(1000,sub(1,exp(product(div(div(product(sum(product(1,likes_count),product(5,comments_count),product(10,shares_count)),10000),pow(fans_count,0.8)),1000),-1)))))
```

Earlier I set it as `-(x)` for the negation. But after I changed like `product(x,-1)`, it works charm.